# "If-Modified-Since" header is null even when it is sent with the request

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, http, caching, .net-7.0

Browser send request with "Is-Modified-Since" header, but the header is not present in the ASP.NET Core Request.Headers collection:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var headers = Response.GetTypedHeaders();
    headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
    {
        MustRevalidate = true,
        NoCache = true,
    };
    var modifiedSince = Request.GetTypedHeaders().IfModifiedSince; //always null
      
    return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/pdf");
}
```

The request looks like this:

```
GET /api/values HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sk;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,cs;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:5002
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 24 Jul 2023 18:16:28 GMT
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.183
sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

or via powershell

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/values" `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
  "Cache-Control"="max-age=0"
  "If-Modified-Since"="Mon, 24 Jul 2023 18:16:28 GMT"
  
}
```

where did the header disappeared? I've checked with Kestrel local development server

Comment: It seems there is a similar [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36291) in github.